# Add new row to dataframe when actionButton is clicked

Tags: r, dataframe, shiny

I'm trying to create a R Shiny application that creates a 1 row dataframe based on the input values, and when an action button is clicked it adds that dataframe as a new row to another dataframe (which starts blank).

I've browsed around StackOverflow but I couldn't find something that addressed my issue.

What I would like to happen is the following:

```
input$one <- "A"
input$two <- "B"
input$three <- "C"

df1 = A | B | C
```

now when I press the actionButton, I would like `df2` (which starts blank) to be the following:

```
df2 = A | B | C
```

next, I want to be able to add more rows. So if I change my input values to the following:

```
input$one <- "X"
input$two <- "Y"
input$three <- "Z"

df1 = X | Y | Z
```

and I click the actionButton again, `df2` should update to be the following:

```
df2 = A | B | C
      X | Y | Z
```

and finally, one last update and click of the actionButton would be the following:

```
input$one <- "1"
input$two <- "2"
input$three <- "3"

df1 = 1 | 2 | 3

*actionButton click*

df2 = A | B | C
      X | Y | Z
      1 | 2 | 3
```

I would like to do this virtually as many times as possible, that every time I click the actionButton it adds whatever is in `df1` as a new row to `df2`. I know that this will have to use rbind, but how can it be done with actionButton?

Comment: Use `rbind` to add the rows

Comment: @akrun right, but how can this be done with using reactive dataframes and an actionButton?

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me.

```
mydata <- data.frame()

  df <- eventReactive(input$add_payer, {
      newrow <- data.frame(ALEMO())
      mydata <<- rbind(mydata, newrow)
    })

  output$all_data <- renderTable(df())
```